# how to store more than one row in MYSQL stored procedure variable?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, normalization

I have a table which have two columns ADMI_ID and DIAG_ID.

```
|--------|--------|
|ADMI_ID |DIAG_ID |
|--------|--------|
|    1   | 46777  |
|    1   | 12457  |
|    2   | 12456  |
|    2   | 36835  |
|--------|--------|
```

I want to fetch this two separate DIAG_ID responding to the same ADMI_ID and store them in a variable in mysql stored procedure or insert them into a temporary table.
Can you please help me ?

Comment: Please provide some context - what do you want to do with this variable or temp table?

Comment: i want to combine it with other table such where I can match ADMI_ID of this table with other table and the resulting table should have something like----|ADMI_ID|Diag_ID_1|Diag_ID_2|.......|......|

Comment: I want to merge the rows with same ADMI_ID and make a new table with three columns

Comment: You mean a [pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/111794)? MySQL doesn't have a built-in pivot operator. See [here](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/).

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am talking about ! Sorry didn't knew the terminology :(

Comment: Can you help me write a query for this ?

Comment: Did you read the links in my comment?

Comment: Yeah I read ur comment ! I want some help to make it working using query